# Transition of triangle svg path in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I would like to create 30 equilateral triangles of different dimensions and colors, in a random position inside the body, that are moving away from the current mouse position, stopping at a short distance from the border of the body.

Here is the code:

```
var body = d3.select("body");
var mouse = [];
var width = 1000;
var height = 600;
var numberOfTriangles = 30;
var isMouseMoving = false;
var triangle = d3.symbol()
    .type(d3.symbolTriangle);    

function drawTriangles(number) {
for(var i=0;i<number;i++){
    var dim = Math.random()*400;
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("d", triangle.size(dim))
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + Math.random()*width + "," + Math.random()*height + ")"; })
        .attr("fill", "rgb("+parseInt(Math.random()*255)+","+parseInt(Math.random()*255)+","+parseInt(Math.random()*255)+")")
        .attr("opacity", 2)
        .attr("class", "path"+i);
}
}

function moveMouse(number) {
if (isMouseMoving) {
    console.log("posix: x="+mouse[0]+",y="+mouse[1]+"\n");
    for(var i=0;i<number;i++){
        svg.select('.path'+i).transition().duration(5)
            .attr({'x':-mouse[0],'y':-mouse[1]})
    }
}
}

var svg = body.append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)
.style("border", "1px solid black")
.on("mousemove", function() {
    mouse = d3.mouse(this);
    isMouseMoving=true;
});


drawTriangles(numberOfTriangles);
d3.timer(function(){moveMouse(numberOfTriangles)});
```

I have few questions:

1) How to position the triangles inside the body? In this way that I have done, a little part of some triangles is outside the body. Math.random()*weight and Math.random()*height are not enough?

2) I saw some examples that implement the transition like I have done, but in my case doesn't work. How can I implement the transition of the triangles so that they move away from the current position of the mouse and they stop at a short distance from the border of the body?

Thank you in advice.

Comment: Which version of d3?

Comment: I am using the v4.

Answer (score 0):

1) It depends on how the triangles are drawn.

If `d3.symbolTriangle` draws lineTo into negative x territory (i think it does), then you have the potential that the left half of your triangle will be cut off by the bounds of your body.

Try adding 1/2 of the triangle's width when you translate it on the x direction.

2) At the moment, your code is attempting to move the triangles to the position of the mouse, not away from it. Here is that working:

```
var body = d3.select("body");
var mouse = [];
var width = 1000;
var height = 600;
var numberOfTriangles = 30;
var isMouseMoving = false;
var triangle = d3.symbol()
  .type(d3.symbolTriangle);

function drawTriangles(number) {
  for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    var dim = Math.random() * 400;
    svg.append("path")
      .attr("d", triangle.size(dim))
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + Math.random() * width + "," + Math.random() * height + ")";
      })
      .attr("fill", "rgb(" + parseInt(Math.random() * 255) + "," + parseInt(Math.random() * 255) + "," + parseInt(Math.random() * 255) + ")")
      .attr("opacity", 2)
      .attr("class", "path" + i);
  }
}

function moveMouse() {
  if (isMouseMoving) {
    //console.log("posix: x="+mouse[0]+",y="+mouse[1]+"\n");

    svg.selectAll('path').each(function(d, i) {
      var self = d3.select(this);
      self.attr('transform', function() {
        return "translate(" + mouse[0] + "," + mouse[1] + ")";
      })
    })

  }
}

var svg = body.append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .style("border", "1px solid black")
  .on("mousemove", function() {
    mouse = d3.mouse(this);
    isMouseMoving = true;
  });


drawTriangles(numberOfTriangles);
d3.timer(function() {
  moveMouse()
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hLcvdpjk/

D3 triangle: https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/src/symbol/triangle.js

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I try to run your code and the triangles doesnt go away from the current mouse position, but go to the current mouse position; I have to do a gradual transition, not an immediate change of position.

Comment: Yes that's right. Well, you need to do a few things before all of that can happen. You need to 1) Figure out what 'away from the mouse' actually means and calculate that 2) save each triangle's current position before it is translated, 3) figure out when the mouse stops moving, 4) then translate each triangle back to its previous position.